# Lipschitz constant higher dimension

Tags: analysis

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $K>0$, i.e. $|f(x)-f(y)|\le K||x-y||$. 
Define $g:\mathbb{R\times \mathbb{R}^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ by $g(t, x)=(x, f(x))$. I want to prove $g$ is Lipschitz in the second variable with Lipschitz constant $K+1$ i.e. $||g(t, x)-g(t, y)||\le (1+K) ||x-y||$, $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R^2}$

I want to know if my proof is correct:

We have: $||g(t, x)-g(t, y)||=||(x, f(x))-(y, f(y))||=||(x-y, f(x)-f(y))||\le||(x-y, 0)||+$ $ +||(0, 0, f(x)-f(y))||\le(1+K)||x-y||$ as $f$ is Lipschitz.

Is my proof correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, up to some typos and details to be added:

- $||(0, 0, f(x)-f(y))||$ should be $||(0, f(x)-f(y))||$;
- maybe it would be better to add the step $||(0, f(x)-f(y))||=\left\lvert f(x)-f(y)\right\rvert$.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote $||(0, 0, f(x)-f(y))||$ because $x, y \in \mathbb{R^2}$